# Real and complex solutions of cubic implicit equation

Tags: cubics

I have faced this differential problem: $(y'(x))^3 = 1/x^4$.

From the fundamental theorem of algebra i know there exist 3 solutions $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$, but formally how can I procede to deduce that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y'(x)^3=\frac{1}{x^4}$, then $y(x)=-3 x^{-1/3}+c$     ........

Comment: yes i find this solution , but the other 2 (complex) solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{-4/3}$$
Use the factorization of $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
This is
$$(y'(x)-x^{-4/3})(y'(x)^2+y'(x)x^{-4/3}+x^{-8/3})$$

Comment: yes but in this way i find only the solution y= -3 / (x^(⅓)) ...  and the other 2 solution?

Comment: you mean:  ( ′()−^(-4/3) ) * ( ′()^2+′()*^(−4/3)+^(−8/3) ) ? 
From the first re-obtain the real solution and solving the 2nd order equation in y' the other 2 complex solution. Correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct, sorry for my typo!

Answer (score 0):

Every number has three cube roots. You only used one of them.

In particular, if a is  real number then the three cube roots are $a^{1/3}$, a real number, $a^{1/3}(cos(2\pi/3)+ isin(2\pi/3))$, and $a^{1/3}(cos(4\pi/3)+ isin(4\pi/3))$.

Given $(y'(x))^3= \frac{1}{x^4}= x^{-4}$, we have 
$y'(x)= x^{-4/3}$, $y'(x)= x^{-4/3}(cos(2\pi/3)+ isin(2\pi/3))$, and $y'(x)= x^{-4/3}(cos(4\pi/3)+ isin(4\pi/3))$.